# PHP memcached client - does its CRC32 work across 32 and 64bit servers?

Tags: php, memcached, 32bit-64bit

PHPs crc32 doesnt give the same values on 32 and 64 bit systems.

memcache client on PHP uses crc32 in its routing algorithm.

My question is : does the routing work across architectures so If I connect to the same servers pool from 32bit box and 64bit box they will work as expected and find each other's data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRC32 is mathematically defined and architecture independent. PHP seems to be tricky in the representation though, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php).

Comment: Thanks mensi.
I know for sure from experience that PHP doesnt always produce the same results from crc32 function on 32 and 64 bit platforms. the question is whether in the memcache hashing implementation this was taken care of.

Comment: @Nir it would be a bug if it produced different results. According to the manual, there might be differences in default representation, the internal value should be the same though.